# how to store a vector as key of a map

Tags: javascript, dictionary, vector, hashmap, memoization

I want to memoize the return result of my function that take two int. i know i could convert the vector as a string like `1-2` but is there another way to do it ?

I tried to set an array as a map but there is no comparison between array

```
let map = new Map();

function gridTraveler(m, n){
    if (m === 0 || n === 0)
        return 0;
    if (m === 1 && n === 1)
        return 1;
    if (map.has([m,n]))
        return map.get([m, n]);
    let res = gridTraveler(m-1, n) + gridTraveler(m, n-1);
    map.set([m, n], res);
    return res;
}
```

Comment: You never add anything to the map.

Comment: When you use an object or array as a Map key, lookup is by object identity, not contents. Each time you write `[m, n]` it creates a new array, which won't be equal to the one that was used as the Map key. It's just like `[1, 2] == [1, 2] ==> false`

Comment: Instead if using an array as the key, you can use nested maps: `map.get(m)?.get(n)`

Comment: Sorry i edited the new version. And yes i know the comparison between two array is false but i want to know if there is another way to make it work in javascript like overriding the equals of an array to compare value inside the array instead of addresses.

Comment: Converting the array to a string will almost certainly be the simplest solution in your case. It's not a general solution for all arrays, but it's fine for an array of numbers.

Answer (score 0):

To memoize the function `gridTraveler` without converting keys to strings, you can serialize the parameters as a unique object key.

In JavaScript, objects or arrays used as keys in Maps are compared by their reference, not by their content [MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#objects_vs._maps). Therefore, you need a method to generate a consistent, unique object reference for each pair of parameters.

Here's an approach keeping integers only:

1. Use a nested map: The outer map keys are `m`, and each `m` maps to another map where the keys are `n`.
2. Check and set values in this two-level map structure.

Here's how you can implement it:

```js
let map = new Map();

function gridTraveler(m, n) {
    if (m === 0 || n === 0) return 0;
    if (m === 1 && n === 1) return 1;

    if (!map.has(m)) map.set(m, new Map());
    const mMap = map.get(m);

    if (mMap.has(n)) return mMap.get(n);

    let res = gridTraveler(m - 1, n) + gridTraveler(m, n - 1);
    mMap.set(n, res);
    return res;
}
```

In this version, `map` is a map where each key is an `m` value, and each value is another map (let's call it `mMap`). The `mMap` has keys of `n` and stores the results. This avoids the need for string conversion and keeps the benefits of memoization.

Answer (score -1):

##### Updated:

Guessing this is what you want:

```
function hashKey(m, n) {
  return [m, n].sort().join();
}

let map = new Map();

function gridTraveler(m, n) {
  if (m === 0 || n === 0) return 0;
  if (m === 1 && n === 1) return 1;

  const key = hashKey(m, n);
  if (map.has(key)) return map.get(key);

  let res = gridTraveler(m - 1, n) + gridTraveler(m, n - 1);
  map.set(key, res);

  return res;
}
```

###### Origin:

If you want to use array value as the key, you must keep the reference.

```
const map = new Map();
const key1 = [1,2];
map.set(key1, 3);
```

> Map(1) {Array(2) => 3}

```
map.get(key1); // works
```

> 3

```
map.get([1,2]);  // not work
```

> undefined

Comment: This answer is of absolutely no use in solving OP's problem, unless you are suggesting adding some data structure that stores each unique `[m, n]` pair, so you can look up specific instance of each pair, to use that instance as the key in the map?

Comment: Yes maybe i have badly formulated my question and it don't solve my problem.

Comment: In fact i choose this solution but i just added a comma separator between the two numbers so there is no error

Comment: @rayankb92 `.join()` uses a comma as the separator by default, so `.join()` is the same as `.join(',')`.